# .appendChild() appends into the end of div

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a booklet with plugin [MOLESKINE NOTEBOOK WITH JQUERY BOOKLET](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/14/moleskine-notebook/), and I want to dynamically add pages to it, using JS.

Though, when I try to add a page, all the stuff that needs to be on separate pages after the title one, appears on the very first page. And the strangest thing here is that after several refreshings or clearing the cache, it all stands as it should.

So, here is the code of the book:

```
<div class="book_wrapper">
    <a id="next_page_button"></a>
    <a id="prev_page_button"></a>
    <div id="loading" class="loading">Загрузка книги...</div>
    <div id="mybook" style="display:none;">
        <div class="b-load" id="book_itself">
            <div>
                <img src="https://helpunicorn.pythonanywhere.com/static/logo.png" style="border-radius: 10px;">
                <h1>Книга добрых дел</h1>
                <br>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <h2 id="user">Пользователь @</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every `div` is supposed to be a separate page.

This is the code of my JS function:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://helpunicorn.pythonanywhere.com/kdd-info/aadev151', function(data) {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML += `${data[0].username} (${data[0].name})`
    document.getElementById('user').innerHTML += data[0].username
    if (data.length != 1) {
        for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = `
                <h1>${data[i].name}</h1>
                <p>${data[i].info}</p>
            `;
            document.getElementById('book_itself').appendChild(div);
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('book_itself').innerHTML += `
        <div>
            <h1>Упс... Эта книга пока пуста...</h1>
            <p>Узнайте, как заполнить её, на сайте</p>
            <br>
            <a href="http://helpunicorn.ru" target="_blank" class="article">
                <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Article" style="width: 41px; height: 16px;">
                    <canvas width="55" height="21" style="width: 55px; height: 21px; top: -2px; left: -4px;">
                    </canvas>
                    <cufontext>HelpUnicorn</cufontext>
                </cufon>
            </a>
        </div>
        `
    }
});
</script>
```

So, I believe the problem is not with the code but with the plugin, because, as I mentioned earlier, it just takes a refreshing or clearing cache. But I'm wondering what's the exact problem with it

[Please, watch a video for a better understanding](https://ufile.io/r7kqw76n)

Comment: Off-topic: the way you inject data into `innerHTML` is a textbook example of a XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @RuudHelderman you mean what? Im new in JS, so I just don't quite understand :)